# Wordpress Query Posts to fetch Posts with Unique Tag

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to write a query post such that it returns a list fixed list of posts from a category along with any of the **one tag** associated with it.  For eg:

```
<?php $arg = array('cat' => '1','showposts' => 10,'offset' => 0); query_posts($arg); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a class="post-link" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); $count=0; if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id); $count++; if ($count == 1) 
{ echo '<a class="tag-link" href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">#'.$tag->name.'</a>'; } } } ?>
```

#### Posts in Topic A

Post_Title_1 #tag1
Post_Title_2 #tag2
Post_Title_3 #tag3
Post_Title_4 #tag2 <-- I don't wan't this Post one as Tag2 has been displayed already.

The issue is I want only posts with unique tags to be shown....  How can i do that... Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$existing_tags = array();

$arg = array('cat' => '1','showposts' => 10,'offset' => 0); query_posts($arg);

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

//get tag and checking if it existed already
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$skip_post = false;

if ($posttags) {
    foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
        $tag_id = $tag->term_id; //the tag's id
        if (isset($existing_tags[$tag_id])) {
            $skip_post = true; //skip this post if the tag already exists
        } else { 
            $existing_tags[$tag_id] = true;
            $skip_post = false; //otherwise track it in our array
        }
        break; //stop after parsing the first tag
    }
}

if ($skip_post) {
    break; //skip the post
}
//display the post and tags as usual
?>
<a class="post-link" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
echo '<a class="tag-link" href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'">#'.$tag->name.'</a>';
?>
```

So basically you need to move the code that gets the tags to the top, check against an array if it already exists. If it does, go to the next post, otherwise display the rest of the post.

Comment: This is a great idea, but its not working. I tried and found that `$posttags[0]->term_id;` doesn't actually return anything. 

We might need to use it as ...
<code>
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
 foreach($posttags as $tag) {
  echo $tag->name . ' ';
 }</code>